# checkForComodification in search method

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

In one of my java project, a class initializes a ArrayList of a Balance object. Every Balance has an accountNum and a getter method getAccountNum() that returns the accountNum. The searchAccount() method searchs for a accountNum and returns the object with the given AccountNum. Here is the search method. itr is a Iterator for the ArrayList

```
    public Balance searchAccount(long accountNum){
        Balance b = new Balance();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            b = itr.next();
            if(b.getAccountNum() == accountNum)
                return b;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

It gives a check For Comodification exception. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: On what line is the exception thrown? What does `b.getAccountNum` do?

Comment: When/Where do you initialize `itr`? It's probably a better idea to initialize it within the same method in which it is used.

Comment: Maybe some thread modifies the collection, while you're iterating other it?

Answer (score 0):

Your list you are iterating through is probably modified somewhere else since it's not local (you declare and initialise it somewhere else). Either make it local, pass its copy to the method or use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)